# Array - Add value depending on other value

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I would like to add values to an array, depending on other values alrdy in the array.

My script:

```
    $today = date("Ymd");
    $finalDate = date('Ymd', strtotime('+2 days'));

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['DTSTART'] <= $finalDate){
            $values[] = array(
                'day' => $value['DTSTART'],
                'type' => $value['SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en']
            );
        }
    }
```

Type is something like this: Non-recyclable waste, Bio-waste, etc.

I want to add colors to the array depending on the waste type.
I tried it like this, but it adds another 'sub-array'.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['DTSTART'] <= $finalDate){
            $values[] = array(
                'day' => $value['DTSTART'],
                'type' => $value['SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en']
            );
            
            switch ($value['SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en']) {
              case "Non-recyclable waste":
                $values[] = array(
                    'color' => 'success'    
                );
                break;
              case "Bio-waste":
                $values[] = array(
                    'color' => 'success'    
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

// Edit:
The Input array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [DTSTART] => 20210712 [DTEND] => 20210713 [TRANSP] => TRANSPARENT [LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en] => streetname [UID] => uid [DTSTAMP] => 20210707T015623Z [DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en] => description [SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=de] => Bio-waste [PRIORITY] => 9 [CLASS] => PUBLIC [STATUS] => CONFIRMED ) [1] => Array ( [DTSTART] => 20210726 [DTEND] => 20210727 [TRANSP] => TRANSPARENT [LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en] => street [UID] => uid [DTSTAMP] => 20210707T015623Z [DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en] => description [SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en] => Non-recyclable waste [PRIORITY] => 9 [CLASS] => PUBLIC [STATUS] => CONFIRMED )
```

Comment: You might perhaps want to provide the input array. // What you probably need is a reference to the freshly crafted `array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an item array with unconditional data (day and type). Add conditional data (color) as needed. Push the array to the main array.

```
$values = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value['DTSTART'] <= $finalDate)
    {
        $item = array(
            'day' => $value['DTSTART'],
            'type' => $value['SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en'],
        );

        switch ($value['SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en'])
        {
            case "Non-recyclable waste":
            case "Bio-waste":
                $item['color'] = 'success';
            break;
            // Add more cases.
        }
        
        $values[] = $item;
    }
}
```